# Robotframework test cases , how topn write a test cases for this scenaries

Tags: python, robotframework

1. Kept KRB5 empty stanza in config and run mmnfs config change - config change will remove empty KR5 stanza
2. With valid KRB5 stanza, KRB5 stanza should not be removed after performing any mmconfig change opertaion
3. Without KRB5 stanza ---> Expected result: mmnfs change config should not create empty KRB5 stanza

Comment: Is this some academic exercise? This is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099480/for-automation-test

Comment: What is a "KRB5 stanza"?

Answer (score 0):

-krb5 is a file

Kept KRB5 empty stanza in config and run mmnfs config change - config change will remove empty KR5 stanza
With valid KRB5 stanza, KRB5 stanza should not be removed after performing any mmconfig change opertaion
Without KRB5 stanza ---> Expected result: mmnfs change config should not create empty KRB5 stanza

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

How to write if condition in robot frame work.here the details below

Log "check krb valid stanza in conf finle"
@{output} native CLI uniquscommand grep -A5 NFS_KRB5/var/mmfs/ces/nfs-config/god's.ganesha.main.conf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).